# Guardar objeto en repositorio MongoDB sin la anotación @Entity

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Actualmente tengo un objeto que si utiliza la anotación `@Entity`, pero dentro de este objeto tengo varios objetos de una librería externa, los cuales no utilizan esta anotación ni tampoco la anotación `@Id`. Evidentemente no puedo modificar estos objetos para añadirles las anotaciones ya que están en una librería externa.

Al intenta guardar mi objeto con esos subobjetos, me da el error:

> references an unknown entity.

Es posible guardar los datos sin tener que recrear la librería externa en mi proyecto añadiendo todas las anotaciones manualmente?

Comment: Crea uno igual propio y copia los datos. A esa clase le pones la anotación `@Entity`.

Comment: podrías probar extender de esas clases  y ponerles la anotación @Entity como dice "Angel"